# Tensorflow CNN Doesn't Accept My Images

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow, tflearn

I'm setting up a CNN with Tflearn on top of Tensorflow. I would like to train it to apply an image filter, so I'm starting off small by providing it with a before/after pair of single-channel grayscale 513x217px images, `data` and `data2`. Here's the code I wrote:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tflearn
import numpy as np

#data and data2 are already defined. They're both a list of lists.

from tflearn.layers.core import input_data, dropout, fully_connected
from tflearn.layers.conv import conv_2d, max_pool_2d
from tflearn.layers.normalization import local_response_normalization
from tflearn.layers.estimator import regression

network = input_data(shape=[None, np.shape(data)[0], np.shape(data)[1], 1], name='input')
network = conv_2d(network, 256, 3, activation='relu', regularizer="L2")
network = regression(network, optimizer='adam', learning_rate=0.01,
loss='categorical_crossentropy', name='target')

model = tflearn.DNN(network, tensorboard_verbose=0)
model.fit({'input': data}, {'target': data2}, n_epoch=20,
snapshot_step=100, show_metric=True, run_id='convnet_mnist')
```

When I run it, I get this error:

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (64, 217) for Tensor u'input/X:0', which has shape '(?, 513, 217, 1)'
```

I don't understand this error, because the number 64 doesn't appear in my code. It seems to indicate that the input format is incorrect, but I can't tell how to fix it. Does anyone know what's causing this?

Comment: What shape is `data2`?

Comment: `data2` is a 513x217 list of lists. It's the same shape as `data` is.

Comment: My instinct was to just put the images in as 2D arrays since they're single-channel. Do you think a different format would work better?

Comment: Seems reasonable, I have no idea where 64 comes from, then.

Comment: So at the line before `model.fit`, you print out the shape of `data` and `data2` and that's what you get? Not somewhere before?

It could be helpful for us to see how those two lists are made.

Comment: Since it's talking about the "feed" value, this should be referring to the data the network is trying to input. So it seems to be seeing your data as having that shape (with the 64 in it). Just in case, it may be worthwhile to post the code of how `data` and `data2` are being defined.

Comment: @chris_anderson Yes, if I add `print np.shape(data)` right before that, it outputs `(513, 217)`.

Comment: @golmschenk I just uploaded the output of `print data` [here](http://filebin.ca/35Ope0OSXfzO/data.txt). Perhaps the complex numbers are messing it up?

Comment: @Reubend, maybe, but I'm not sure how you'd get 64 from that. Does `data2` have the same format?

Comment: Yes, they both have identical formats.

Comment: I just tried casting all of the complex numbers into floats, but the `(64, 217)` error still appears, so I don't think that's the issue.